# Python Data Storage Method

Tags: python, database, data-management

I am trying to create a database of variable in python from a large csv file. Any given row in the csv file can be uniquely identified from 4 columns.

To give an idea of the data structure:

```
Supplier A
    Tariff RateA
        Region 1
            Payment Method 1
            Payment Method 2
        Region 2
            Payment Method 1

    Tariff Rate B
        Region 1
            Payment Method 1
            Payment Method 2
        Region 2
            Payment Method 1

Supplier B etc...
```

Once I can uniquely identify the row I am performing calculations using other information in that row to produce a list of three, two dimensional arrays.

I will then create a dictionary linking each variable in the database with its respective array.

I would then like to be able to retrieve these arrays for comparison/ analysis etc...

In order to create the database I have copied the code below which is really slow and I'm currently unsure if creating an empty list before each for loop will have the desired result? Any input or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
supplier_log = []
for supplier in Tariff_Book.Supplier_Name:
    if supplier not in supplier_log:
        print("Supplier: " + supplier)
        supplier_log.append(supplier)
        tariff_log = []
        temp = Tariff_Book.query('Supplier_Name == @supplier')
        for tariff in temp.Tariff_Name:
            if tariff not in tariff_log:
                print("Tariff: " + tariff)
                tariff_log.append(tariff)
                region_log = []
                temp = Tariff_Book.query('Supplier_Name == @supplier & Tariff_Name == @tariff' )
                for region in temp.Region:
                    if region not in region_log:
                        print("Region: " + str(region))
                        region_log.append(region)
                        payment_method_log = []
                        temp = Tariff_Book.query('Supplier_Name == @supplier & Tariff_Name == @tariff & Region == @region')
                        for payment_method in temp.Payment_Method:
                            if payment_method not in payment_method_log:
                                print("Payment Method: " + payment_method)
                                payment_method_log.append(payment_method)
```

Comment: Do you need to go through every tariff for every supplier? Or just the tariffs associated with that supplier?

Comment: It would be every tariff for every supplier